# Create Publishing Page using Client Object Model (Jquery)

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, jquery

I am trying to create a publishing page (site page) using SharePoint 2010, Jquery, Client Object Model.

Any reference or help will be appreciated.

Let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Server features, including Publishing are not supported in the Client Object Model (in SharePoint 2010), you'll need to use the Server object model to create pages.

I'm not saying it's impossible, but you may have to end up with something quite 'hacky' to get it work.

You'd need to basically create a new template redirect page item in the Pages library, and set the appropriate content type (that matches your desired Page Layout's content type). However, if the Page Layout is new to the Pages library, the content type will need to be added to the list. All of this is handled by the Server object model code for you.

If you do need some sort of automated way of creating lots of pages, triggered by something the user clicks on the page, you could implement this in an application page perhaps, which runs the server side code required, or write a web service (that implements the server side code) hosted in SharePoint that can be invoked by jQuery.